# Is it possible to use a operator map to auto generate a specified operator?

Tags: python, dictionary, operators

For I have some rules saved in mysql db.

```
+----+---------+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| id | rule_id | field | operator | value | order | 
+----+---------+-------+----------+-------+-------+
|  1 |       1 |     5 |        2 |     8 |     1 | 
|  2 |       1 |    10 |        2 |     2 |     2 |   
|  3 |       1 |     4 |        2 |     1 |     3 |  

...

# operator 2 is equal to GREATER_THAN for example
```

Then I want to filter data list using the related rule operator, as below's code showed

```py
operator = "LESS_THAN"   # get from mysql db

target_value = 8

list1 = [{'clicks':5, "views":7, 'id':1234}, {'clicks':5, "views":9, 'id':1235}]

filtered_list = [i['id'] for i in  filter(lambda item: item['views'] > target_value, list1)]

# filter the list according to operator > ,target_value 8 for example.
```

Is it possible to use a map relationship like

```py
operation_map = {
    "LESS_THAN" : <,
    "GREATER_THAN": >,
    "EQUAL":=
}
```

to make something like below happed  instead of `if operator == 'GREATER_THAN' :  pass` syntax?

```py
filtered_list = [i['id'] for i in  filter(lambda item: item['views'] operation_map[operator] target_value, list1)]
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated, great thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? operators are more readable and if your class objects have implemented them you can use just a lambda function to sort them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `operator` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

```
import operator

operator_map = {'LESS_THAN': operator.lt,
                'GREATER_THAN': operator.gt,
                'EQUAL': operator.eq}

filtered_list = [i['id'] for i in  filter(lambda item: operator_map[operator](item['views'], target_value), list1)]
```

Add other operators as necessary.